# Filter tuples inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to filter a tuple inside a list of lists based on its second item being "".

for the below list

[[("AA","AA"),("QQ","")],[("CC",""),("QQ","")],...]

I would like to get

[[("AA","AA")],[],...]

I have already tried this

```
[(tup[0] for tup in sub_list if tup[0]!="") for sub_list in list]
```

but get a list of

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at ]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses `(x for x in ...)` leads to a generator expression while square brackets `[x for x in ...]` is a list comprehension that yelds a list.

Also, as you compare to `''` empty string last tuple element, this is `tup[1]`.

```
>>> [[tup for tup in sub_list if tup[1] != ""] for sub_list in lst]
[[('AA', 'AA')], []]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to the question (this output is not the same as what is described to be the valid result)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this `[<generator object <genexpr> at ]` is not an error or something.

Try printing it in a loop, maybe like this:

```
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Its true... after looping over it and again over the result received from the first loop I get the first items on the tuple, but the filter does not work and I do not get the full tuple...

Answer (score 0):

What about using the... `filter` function?

```
[filter(lambda x: x[1]!="", sublist) for sublist in list]
```

**EDIT**: reading other answers, I came across `all`, which is pretty neat in this case:

```
[filter(all, sublist) for sublist in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You nested a generator comprehension inside a list comprehension, you should just nest a list comprehension  instead.

```
L = [[('aa','')],[('aa','bb')]]
[[item for item in sublist if item[1] != ''] for sublist in L ]
>> [[], [('aa', 'bb')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[tup for tup in sub_list if all(tup) and tup] for sub_list in lst]
```